# What does [ <- ] mean in why3?

Tags: smt, frama-c, why3

I'm using Frama-C, Alt-Ergo and Why3 for system verifications. One proof obligation generated in Frama-C and sent to Why3 is shown below (this is the Why3 version):

```
(p_StableRemove t_1[a_5 <- x] a_1 x_1 a i_2)
```

I'd like to know what `t_1[a_5 <- x]` means.

Is it an assignment of `x`to `a_5` before accessing `t_1[a_5 <- x]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ <- ]` is the notation for array modification in Why3. However, unlike in imperative languages, `t[i <- v]` is a *functional update* of `t`, i.e. a (new) array that maps `i` to `v`, and all other valid indexes of `t` to their value in `t`. `t` itself is unmodified, you are creating a new array by copying most of the contents of `t`.

These are the relevant part of the  [Why3 standard library on arrays](http://why3.lri.fr/stdlib-0.82/array.mlw.html)

```
function set (a: array ~'a) (i: int) (v: 'a) : array 'a =
    { a with elts = M.set a.elts i v }

function ([<-]) (a: array 'a) (i: int) (v: 'a) : array 'a = set a i v
```